# Duda respecto a TabView y Section en SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode

Pido ayuda si alguien sabe como realizar esto, quiero que al ir a perfil. Y la barra de navegación quede donde dice "Perfil" quede en modo inline por defecto y  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando le damos un deslizar para abajo me muestre en el modo por defecto. Subo otra imagen de como quiero que quede al darle swip Donw.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  En la aplicación WhatsApp esta configurado de esa manera. Busque en la documentación pero no la encontré.

```
 struct PerfilView: View {
    var body: some View {
         VStack {
            List {
                Image("1640669")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                Text("Ester Exposito")
                    .font(.footnote)
                Section(header: Text("Direccion")) {
                    ForEach (1..<4){ item in

                        Text("")

                    }.accentColor(.red)
                }

                Section(header: Text("")) {
                    Text("")
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct PerfilView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PerfilView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de los que has intentado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @Bicho Ahi agregue lo que tengo, no creo que te sirve de mucho ya que no se exactamente como implementar. Por eso es que pido una ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás utilizando un navigation controller que te lleva a la pantalla de perfil, en el view controller, dentro de **viewWillAppear** añade:

```
if (@available(iOS 11, *))  {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;
}
```